# Addressable/uri load error jekyll build

Tags: jekyll

I'm having trouble fiinding the source of this problem. I am currently working on a project that uses jekkyl and gulp, and when I try to do jekyll build I get an error saying "cannot load such file -- addressable/uri (LoadError)". I did a 'gem install addressable' and it installed correctly but I still get the error.
[image]

Comment: try installing `bundler` and run `bundle exec jekyll build`

Comment: YES! Thank you so much. @ashmaroli